# Font weight and style do not map correctly in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, fonts, mapping

When I have the following piece of Xaml in a WPf project:

```
    <StackPanel
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock
            FontSize="40"
            FontFamily="Segoe UI"
            FontWeight="Light"
            Text="This is a test (light)" />
        <TextBlock
            FontSize="40"
            FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
            Text="This is a test (font.light)" />
        <TextBlock
            FontSize="40"
            FontFamily="Segoe UI"
            Text="This is a test (normal)" />
        <TextBlock
            FontSize="40"
            FontFamily="Segoe UI"
            FontWeight="SemiBold"
            Text="This is a test (semibold)" />
        <TextBlock
            FontSize="40"
            FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"
            Text="This is a test (font.semibold)" />
        <TextBlock
            FontSize="40"
            FontFamily="Segoe UI"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Text="This is a test (bold)" />
    </StackPanel>
```

The fonts render as expected. However, when I use this in a Silverlight project, the textblocks where FontWeight is Light or Semibold do not render correctly; the FontWeight="Light" version just uses the normal font and the FontWeight="Semibold" uses the bold version. When the fontname is explictly stated, i.e. "Segoe UI Light" and "Segeo UI Semibold" it works as expected. It seems as if Silverlight does not map some FontWeight values to the correct font as WPF does. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Only certain fonts are included out of the box with Silverlight.  The ones that are not showing correctly are simply not available unless you specifically include them in your project and distribute them as part of the xap.

Greg